# How to pass data variable from each to the with in Meteor?

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze

I am trying to pass git variable to settings which is wrapping with with as shown below
If we can see right now it is setting.gitlab but i want to make it dynamically like setting.git where git is a variable mentioned in each loop .

```
 {{#each git in gitlabFields}}
        {{#with settings.gitlab}}
        <div data-value={{@index}}>{{git}}</div>
        <div>hihi</div>
            <div class="rc-user-info__row">
                <div class="rc-input">
                    <label class="rc-input__label">
                        <div >
                                
                                <div class="rc-input__title" style="display: inline-block;" >{{_ label}}{{equal default value '*'}}</div>
                                
                                
                        </div>
                    <!-- {{#each gitlabFields}} -->
                    <div id="dynamicFields">
                            <div class="rc-input__wrapper" >
                                    <input type="text" name="{{git}}" value="{{value}}" class="rc-input__element js-input" disabled="{{./disabled}}"/>
                                </div>
                    </div>
                        
                        <!-- {{/each}} -->
                    </label>
                </div>
            </div>
        {{/with}}
        {{/each}}
```

git variable is not accessible here settings.git
Its showing undefined .

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `settings` is an accessible Object, you can write a helper, that resolves the value:

```js
Template.myTemplate.helpers({
  getGitSettings (settings, key) {
    return settings[key]
  }
})
```

If you want to decouple `settings` from the template or avoid passing it through the whole display list you can also define it within the Template module as private variable:

```js
const gitSettings = { ... };

Template.myTemplate.helpers({
  getGitSettings (settings, key) {
    return gitSettings[key]
  }
})
```

If this pattern is used among many Templates you can also define a global helper:

```js
const gitSettings = { ... };

Template.registerHelper('gitSettings', function (key) {
 return gitSettings[key]
})
```

and use it via

```html
{{#each field in gitlabFields}}
  {{#with gitSettings field}}...{{/with}}
{{/each}}
```

Comment: How to pass data context dynamically whose value we are getting from array like settings.x , settings.y

Comment: Please improve your question. If you have a more complex case then your question code is not explicit enough.